# Find the shortest distance from the origin of $\mathbb{R}^3$ to the surface $xyz=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need some help with this problem:

> Find the shortest distance from the origin of $\mathbb{R}^3$ to the surface $xyz=1$. Hint: find the normal of $x^2+y^2+z^2$, where $z=\frac{1}{xy}$, use calculations of problem 2(d).

The hint tells me to use the calculations of a previous problem that asked to determine the nature of the critical points of $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+\frac{1}{x^2y^2},\quad xy\neq 0$.

From that problem I got this:$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x.y)=2x-\frac{2}{x^3y^2}$$ $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=2y-\frac{2}{x^2y^3}$$ from that, I know that $x^2y=\pm 1$ and $xy^2=\pm1$, thus the critical points are $(\pm1,\pm1)$.

Then I calculated the second partial derivatives and the dicriminant $$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(x,y)=2+\frac{6}{x^4y^2}$$ $$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(x,y)=2+\frac{6}{x^2y^4}$$ $$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}(x,y)=\frac{4}{x^3y^3}$$ $$\Delta_f(\mathbf{x})=4+\frac{12}{x^2y^4}+\frac{12}{x^4y^2}+\frac{20}{x^6y^6}$$ and for both $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$ I got $\Delta_f(\pm1,\pm1)=48>0$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(\pm1,\pm1)=8>0$, thus the point $(\pm1,\pm1)$ is local minimum of $f$.

What should I do next? How do I caluculate the minimum distance from the origin to the surface if I have this calculations?

Comment: So $(1,1,1)$ and $(-1,-1,1)$ are the points on your surface that are closest to the origin. Hence the distance to the surface is the distance to them, $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Why did you add $1$ for the $z$ coordinate?

Comment: Because $z=\frac{1}{xy}$ on the surface.

Comment: I see. So all I need to do is calculate the norm of the vector that connects those points to the origin, and I'll end up with $\sqrt{3}$ as you said, that's all?

Comment: Yes, that's all.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: It is $$x^2+y^2+z^2\geq 3$$ for $$x=1,y=z=-1$$
$$\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{3}\geq \sqrt[3]{(xyz)^2}$$

Comment: I don't understand, how did you came up with that?

Comment: It's AM/${}$GM.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Arithmetic mean/geometric mean.

Answer (score 2):

Then it is just a simple substitution back in the function equation i.e. $$f(\pm 1,\pm 1)=1+1+{1\over 1\cdot 1}=3$$thus the minimum distance is $3$ and happens at $(\pm 1,\pm 1)$.